# monotouch dialog cell sizing and section caption color

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am using monotouch dialog to generate a view. I managed to change the background color by subclassing DialogViewController, but the contrast with the section caption makes the text hard to read. How do I change the section caption color?

I am also using a StyledStringElement as a button in the same view. I cant seem to figure out how to shrink this element so that it looks more like a button. Please provide examples. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue I used a glassbutton with the it's  HandleTapped handler as below.

```
            var butt = new GlassButton(new RectangleF(80,150,150,50))
        {
            Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(22),
            NormalColor = UIColor.Red,     
        };

    void HandleTapped (GlassButton obj)
    {

    }
```

as for the colors, I used miguel's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590161/monotouch-dialog-section-font). Hope this helps someone down the road.